# Polar decomposition varient

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a factorisation to do, and I think that a varient of Polar decomposition will give me what I need, although I'm not sure of the exact form.

I have 
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{UDU}^*\mathbf{x}
\end{equation*}
and I wish to solve for $\mathbf{x}$. We have
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M},~\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times 1},~\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M}.
\end{equation*}
Here $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix, with elements of the form $e^{i\theta}$. Also $\mathbf{U}$ in an orthonormal unitary matrix, with rows which define basis vectors in $\mathbb{C}^M$. The eigenvalues of $\mathbf{D}$ are (with extremely high probability) unrelated to the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{U}$. $\mathbf{U}$ is known, $\mathbf{D}$ is not.

A further constraint is that all elements in $\mathbf{x}$ are $1$ or $-1$, although this could be relaxed.

Comment: Why not just multiply both sides on the left by $\left(UDU^*\right)^{-1}$?

Comment: As I stated, D is unknown. Its general form is known, i.e, values lying on the unit circle, but not the actaul values

Answer (score 0):

It's an ill-posed problem. Necessarily (since $D$ is unitary) $y^*y=x^*x=n$. We assume that $y$ is known and satisfies the previous relation. Note that $z=U^*y$ is known, $z^*z=n$ and $z=DU^*x$. If $D=diag((e^{i\theta_k})_k)$, then $z_k=e^{i\theta_k}\sum_jU^*_{k,j}x_j$ and $|z_k|=|\sum_jU^*_{k,j}x_j|(=\alpha_k)$. When $x$ varies, $\alpha_k$ can have at most $2^n$ values; then, in general, the problem has no solutions.